# Force two lines in inline-block

Tags: html, css

I need to insert an inline block in the middle of other text.

**Text in the block should ALWAYS be wrapped into two lines** (except when there's only one word).

Content of the inline-block is unknown.
The width should change according to the content.

Examples:

[image: Example]
[image: Example 2]

My code:

```css
div.main {
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 30px;
 width: 630px;
}

div.two-lines {
 display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40%;
    height: 27px;
    background: #35b1e6;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #6df0ff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* This needs to go */
div.two-lines:first-of-type {
 width: 194px;
}

div.two-lines:nth-of-type(2) {
 width: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 In the middle of a paragraph
 <div class="two-lines">INLINE-BLOCK, WHICH CONTAINS TWO EQUALLY LONG LINES.</div>, 
 with text preceding and following it.
 
 Some more text, and here comes a
 <div class="two-lines">SHORT ONE</div>!
 You see? Two lines!
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to do this without JavaScript. Does you text within `two-lines` come from a server-controlled source? Can you break it there?

Comment: I can. I just wanted to know if it's possible with pure CSS or not.

Comment: open to some hacky way?

Answer (score 0):

One *hacky* way is to duplicate the text (using data attribute) then you always force the main text to be one line thus it will define the main width then use the duplicated text to take only 50% of that width and you will have 2 lines with almost the same width:

```css
div.two-lines {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px 0;
  color: #6df0ff;
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
}

div.two-lines::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  opacity:0;
}
div.two-lines::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:55%; /*a litte bigger than 50% to avoid 3 lines */
  background: #35b1e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-lines" data-text="INLINE-BLOCK, WHICH CONTAINS TWO EQUALLY LONG LINES."></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="some more text here"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  text here"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="SHORT ONE"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="one"></div>
```

The only drawback with this method is that you will have extra space on the right due to the full width text. We only need to find a way to get rid of it in order to be able to include it within the text.

Another intresting way (still hacky) is to rely on CSS grid where you don't need to duplicate the text. You have to set the width of the text to be 50%. The trick is that this width will be based on the width of the track that is defined by the text content *(yes a bit complicated)*

```css
div.two-lines {
  display: inline-grid;
  margin:5px 0;
  color: #6df0ff;
  position:relative;
}

div.two-lines::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background: #35b1e6;
  padding:10px;
  width:55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-lines" data-text="INLINE-BLOCK, WHICH CONTAINS TWO EQUALLY LONG LINES."></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="some more text here"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  text here"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="SHORT ONE"></div>
<div class="two-lines" data-text="one"></div>
```

Comment: Might want to try these with the text before and after the split-line boxes... They look a little off (to me). Like the hack though :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey as I said there is a drawback with this hack which is the right space ;) so probably someone else may find a workaround for it

Comment: When I use the HTML provided in the first example, the text for the inline blocks doesn't stay contained in the dark blue area (on Chrome 71 on Windows 10). Looks fine standalone.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you show me a screenshot .. using also Chrome but windows 8

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh my god it's too ugly ... this is because you didn't use text as data attribute, the trick rely on this, you cannot keep the text inside

Comment: Got it, helps if I read all of the text of the answer. Interesting hack.